# Can the developer tools window of Internet Explorer 9 be docked to the main browser window?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, docking, web-developer-toolbar

All other current versions of browsers have some form of developer tools and are attached to the main browser window or can be "docked" to it. At least this is true on Windows 7 for Google Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and Safari.

But for Internet Explorer 9, the developer tools are always in a separate window.

The ie9 devtools window has a "pin" icon/button - but for me it does nothing at all.

This extra window makes things really confusing on the small screen of a netbook when comparing behaviour of all the browsers.

Should the "pin" button do what I want? Is there some other way to do it? All the other browsers developer tools are quite usable on a little netbook.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try ctrl+p? 
Is the shortcut for that action on IE 9

Comment: When the pin button is disabled, this also does nothing.